# How to show $\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{d} =\prod_{p|n} \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function, mobius-function

how to prove:
$$\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu^2(d)}{d} =\prod_{p|n} \left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)$$

$\mu : \Bbb N\rightarrow \Bbb R$

$\mu(1)=1$

$ \mu(n)=
\begin{cases}
0  &,\;\;\; \text{if $\,n\,$ is divisible by a square prime number} \\{}\\
(-1)^r &,\;\;\; \text{if $\,n=p_1^1\cdots p_r^1\,$}  \\
\end{cases}
 $

Comment: Expand the Euler product on the right. The result will be a sum of things of the form $1/m$, where $m$ ranges over all products of those primes dividing $n$. Incidentally, $\mu(d)^2$ is $0$ if $d$ has any repeated prime factors and $1$ otherwise, so the sum on the left is comprised of those reciprocals of the form $1/m$, where $m$ ranges over products of primes dividing $n$...

Comment: Note that both sides are unchanged if we replace $n$ by $\prod_{p \mid n}{p}$, so it suffices to consider squarefree $n$. Further note that both sides are multiplicative, so it suffices to consider prime $n$, which is trivial.

Comment: Related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182720/prove-that-fracn-phin-sum-limits-d-mid-n-frac-mu2d-phid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function
$$
\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{d}
$$
is [multiplicative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) (since both $\mu$ and $d$ are multiplicative and multiplication is distributive over addition). That is, if $(n_1,n_2)=1$, then
$$
\sum_{d\mid n_1n_2} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{d}=\sum_{d\mid n_1} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{d}\sum_{d\mid n_2} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{d}
$$
Obviously
$$
\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1+\frac1p\right)
$$
is multiplicative.

The equation is true for powers of primes; that is, both sides send $p^n\mapsto1+\frac1p$. Therefore, it is true for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ n=p_1^{r_1}\ldots p_k^{r_k}$, now on R.H.S. one needs to look at only those $d/n$ such that $d= p_1^{a_1}\ldots p_k^{a_k}$ where $a_i =0$ or $1$. So R.H.S. is sum of reciprocals of all combinations of the primes $p_1 \ldots p_k$ . Now if one expands L.H.S its the same.